# Trying to change path using Python

Tags: python, operating-system, command-prompt, vpn

I'm trying to switch countries using python and nordvpn.

I'm using the following code :

```
 server = "nordvpn -c -g \'"+random.choice(windows_countries)+"\'"+" > /dev/null 2>&1"
 print(server)
 os.system(server)
```

I get the following error message :

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

My guess is I need to change the path. I tried the following line, but I got the same error message.

```
 server = "nordvpn -c -g \'"+random.choice(windows_countries)+"\'"+" > /dev/null 2>&1"
 print(server)
 os.chdir("C:/Program Files/NordVPN")
 os.system(server)
```

Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Is `> /dev/null 2>&1` supposed to work in Windows?

Comment: Perhaps there is no executable called `nordvpn` installed on your system? What happens if you try to execute the same command on the command prompt directly?

Comment: works perfectly ! the problem is really the path.

Comment: problem was indeed the > /dev/null 2>&1 line

Answer (score 1):

Use the `subprocess` module, in particular see the section about replacing `os.system()` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system